Movie About a Turbulent Girl
I have been searching for a movie that I saw 5-6 years ago. It was about a divergent girl who (I assume) has psychological problems. Details that I remember:

It looked like the movie was shot around late 90's - early 00's
Movie takes place in a small country town in U.S.A
The girl is between 15-20 years old and living with her family.
Her mother is not around (I don't remember if she was dead) and the girl's father is angry about her behavior.
The girl was talking about running away from the town with her friend.
(I am not 100% sure about the details of this one) In one scene, the girl was in a bar with one of her friends, and she was taking a boy to the back of the bar. She was flirting with the boy for a while, and then she told people that she had sex with him. Then her lie was exposed, and the boy beat her up.
As I remember, the girl was looking like young Winona Ryder.

Any help?

UGH!! I got excited because I was reading too fast and thought it said Tank Girl. :(

It reminded me of the movie "Twelve Mile Road"
Official tag line: 

A divorced farmer (Tom Selleck) deals with the unexpected arrival of his troubled daughter (Maggie Grace).

From Wikipedia:

After a rough divorce, farmer Stephen Landis (Tom Selleck) lives a normal life living on his ranch in Idaho with his girlfriend Leah (Anna Gunn) and her daughter, Roxanne (Tegan Moss). But life once again gets complicated for Stephen when his daughter Dulcie (Maggie Grace) comes for a summer visit after having a fight with her mother (Wendy Crewson). Stephen's absence as a father and failed marriage with Angela left Dulcie in a rebellious state as a troubled teenager. Stephen's ex-wife attempts to warn him of their daughter's disruptive behaviors, but combined with his feelings of guilt, the relationship threatens to ruin his present relationship and life with Leah. Dulcie and her father try to begin to heal their problems, but the damage may be too great to resolve and jeopardizes the chance of a bright future for either of them.


It's much better to post answers as answers... and would actually be incorrect for you to post it as a comment... so you're doing the right thing!  One thing, is this your own plot description? If so, that's fine... if you've copied it from somewhere, you need to use quote markup and include a link to the source. We don't allow plagiarism here.

Ok! Sorry, it wasn't my intention to plagiarize anything. On the other sites like this one, we usually put the link to IMDB and copy and paste the description of the plot from it, just to make things easier. As I was on my coffee-break from work and we can't access any entertainment sites there, I did copy from Wikipedia and I forgot to add the link from it. And since I already gained 3 points negative, I think I won't be able to make any comment here any time soon... Maybe I'll stick to the other sites. Thank you.

Sorry for the late answer but no, this is not the movie that I've been searching for. Thanks for your interest.
